# What's the difference between these two formulas and how are these called?

Tags: terminology, kinematics

I just want to know the differences between these two formulas:

$h = h_0 + v_0  t ± \frac{1}{2} g  t^2$

and

$y = y_0 + v_{0y} t + \frac{1}{2} g t^2$

Also, how are these called in English?

Comment: The formulas are the same, just using a different variable to represent position.  That is, y or h.  My initial guess was that the top formula was horizontal, and the bottom was vertical, but if so, the top formula should have an A, instead of a g.

Comment: They are called kinematics formulas.

Comment: They are also commonly called SUVAT equations - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the two formulas look the same.  In english, we write these formulas as:

In the horizontal (or x-direction):
$x = x_0 + v_{0x}t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$, where $x$ represents distance in the horizontal direction, $x_0$ represents the initial distance, $v_{0x}$ is the initial velocity in the x-direction (sometimes instead written as $u_x$) and finally  $a$ is the acceleration in the horizontal direction.

Similarly, we have for the vertical, or y-direction:

$y = y_0 + v_{0y}t + \frac{1}{2}gt^2$

Notice I have replaced $a$ with $g$, since in most problems, the acceleration in the y-direction is due to gravity, so $a=g$.

These equations are referred to as "kinematic equations" along with these additional formulas:

$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$ and $v = u + at$.

Comment: h also could represent the height above a surface which is probably why g was still in it.

Comment: Yes, h represents the height. Also, when I asked the names I meant the formula's name, I guess the first one is "vertical position as a function of time", but I don't know the second, could it be the same?

Comment: based on what you have said, both formulas are identical.  They both have the same name.

Comment: @Chris so why in the first one I can user positive or negative gravity (pointing up or down) and in the other just positive?

Comment: The first one is wrong that's why, it should just be +, assuming your convention is g = -9.8m/s^2.

Comment: @Chris but will it not change depending on the direction I choose? For example, a guy throws a ball up, when it's going up the gravity will be negative, when it starts going down the gravity will be positive, isn't it?

Comment: @Adami: No, the direction of g does not depend on the direction your ball is moving. It only depends on the orientation of your chosen set of coordinate axes.